# Unable to execute the program in hadoop

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop, mapreduce

When I created a Jar and compiled in windows and tried to run in Hadoop. It's throwing an error while running this script

```
admin1@admin1:/usr/local/hadoop/conf$ hadoop jar wordcount.jar com.shailu.wordcount.WordCount input/wordcount output/wordcount
```

Error is:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:
>   com/shailu/wordcount/WordCount : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Answer (score 3):

Nothing wrong with ur execution,

Looks like there is a mismatch in the compile and the execute environment.
type "java -version" in both the environments , i.e. windows and hadoop(linux/unix)

My doubt is you have compiled the code in a higher version like 1.8, change it to 1.7 or so, you should be ok.

or while compiling choose the same java version as the hadoop environment have.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered such problem. You need keep the compiler consistently between windows and hadoop or hadoop compiler higher than windows'. See picture I screenshot from Internet(contain a little Chinese, you also can refence this website if you can open it: [JDK compiler version mapping minor.major](http://blog.csdn.net/sunyujia/article/details/2027399)). I guess JDK1.8.x is mapping major.minor version 52.0.
[image: Picture of JDK compiler version mapping minor.major]

```
JDK编译器版本-------------JDK compiler version
target参数----------------target parameter
十六进制 minor.major------hexadecimal minor.major
十进制 minor.major--------decimal minor.major
不能带 target 参数--------can't add target parameter
默认为--------------------default
```